# Which folders can FCKEditor run without?

Tags: fckeditor

We have FCKeditor in one of our projects, but we are striving for a stream-lined build process.  I've noticed there seems to be a lot of bloat within the FCKEditor (images, HTML files, language.js files etc.) which are probably not used.  Does anyone know which folders/files can be removed without affecting its functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can remove unnecessary connectors - for example, I removed connectors for php, perl, lasso etc (I used ASP .NET). You can find connectors on editor/filemanager/connectors/
2. You can remove _sample directory too.
3. If multilingual support is unnecessary, you can remove unnecessary languages from editor/lang

Comment: what are connectors by the way?

Comment: Connectors are program modules, which allow you to upload file using FCKEditor. They work on the server side - so they are different for different server-side programming language

Comment: Any directory that starts an underscore can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Amber's points you can remove all the plugins you don't want. Many, if not most are off by default.